# Why this passed function is giving me an error in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In the app.tsx I got a function like this.

Since I am not returning nothing I am setting the return value as void

```
const addToDo = (newToDoText: string): void => {
    setToDos([...todos, { id: 4, text: newToDoText, completed: false }]);
  };
```

I passed this function into the form

```
<ToDoForm addToDo={addToDo} />
```

The error occur in ToDoForm when I write like this

```
   //Error Here
    const ToDoForm = ({ addToDo : () => void}) => {
```

There are two error, 1 on closing bracket `}`  which said expression expected.

Another one is on `=>` arrow which said `; is expected`

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to combine property destructuring syntax along with an object type annotation (but they must be exclusive syntax). Try one of these refactors:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEE0HsFdQYwIYDtQBcCeAHApmgFrpgE6SYDOoZ2mCRCq2ANuqIwJYDWuqebZAXAFgAUBhygAKpAAikAGKQiAWwAKJcqAC8oAN4jQoBABMjU2f1AAKJNgDuZyBOwAPVBbKoibJAHMAlFoAfKAAbpBsRgDcIgC+0cIiIJIEKOgw8Mig0FT42EqsnNy8AiJwkEgekjLyikoAjFpWxKQCVbIKymotAZrBesIGzeQAdMam1ZGgSdZ2Dk6u7p7e-kGh4Uax8YlgULCIKEbYHkTQcKjQREW4AERjDtegQ9hEGAVc+HxCwmUVqG01ygATI1LDpDCYHKAYhYHB1VOoyD0+sAAFSgYYY0Ao4BxETbUAAeSIoDSe0yti8DFyjwRaCwuG87BsXx+lVhtQAzCChq0wXdqhYZvZqvM3JQlr4kWsIlCpf1BgjRhCJlMwEK5i4xcdllKwhFNnjhEkifBIEoAEbeK6gRlWuniZBGUCHY6nc6XJ1PF7oFnlNnVOEAFhBfOVsihFlD43MVhswtkosWXklqz1TpictR6Mx2NxwiAA)

```ts
// You can type the props separately like this:
type ToDoFormProps = {
  addToDo: (newToDoText: string) => void;
};

// Then you can use them like this:
const ToDoForm1 = (props: ToDoFormProps) => {
  props.addToDo; // (newToDoText: string) => void
};

// You can destructure the "addToDo" property like this:
const ToDoForm2 = ({ addToDo }: ToDoFormProps) => {/* ... */};

// Or you can write the props type inline:
const ToDoForm3 = (props: { addToDo: (newToDoText: string) => void }) => {
  props.addToDo; // (newToDoText: string) => void
};

// Or combine the inline type and destructured property:
const ToDoForm4 = ({ addToDo }: { addToDo: (newToDoText: string) => void }) => {/* ... */};
```